# Easy Route Configuration

Tags: asp.net-web-api

How do you use Web Api 2 use a route like this : " testdomain.de/Az809Aj " . When someone calls this URL , is a method to be called , in which I can process id behind the slash . How do I configure the route for it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default2",
            routeTemplate: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```